# What does the word pronounced as "ma" in cantonese chinese mean in English?

Tags: translation, cantonese

What does the word pronounced as "ma" in Cantonese Chinese mean in English?  I understand that this syllable has five different meanings according to how it is inflected.  What are the five different meanings of this syllable?

Comment: Which character?

Answer (score 5):

Since *ma* in Jyutping isn't a valid syllable according to Cantonese [phonotactics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics), I assume you mean Jyutping *maa*.

Modern Hong Kong Cantonese has six tones, of which five are indeed valid contours for the syllable *maa*. I'll use the Jyutping tone numbers below, giving an example word for each.

- First tone (high level): *maa1* 媽 (mother), 孖 (twin)
- Second tone: not possible
- Third tone (mid level): *maa3* 嗎 (question particle)
- Fourth tone (low falling): *maa4* 麻 (hemp)
- Fifth tone (low rising): *maa5* 馬 (horse)
- Sixth tone (low level): *maa6* 罵 (scold, abuse)

Comment: FYI, `ma` is a valid representation of `/maː/` if you're using Yale Romanization.

Comment: Actually maa2 is possibly in tone sandhi configurations, like 麻麻地 maa4 maa4*2 dei6*2.